# Error related to memory while executing code

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am getting below error on executing nodejs/nestjs application:

> [Nest] 6204  - 05/05/2022, 4:21:33 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader]
> GraphQLModule dependencies initialized +1ms       1: 00007FF713B4285F
> napi_wrap+119263  2: 00007FF713AE9526
> v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NextTableOffset+38102
> 3: 00007FF713A79D09 std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits
>
> > ::operator<<+52265  4: 00007FF7142DB8F0 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+323456  5: 00007FF7142DAE37
> > v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+320711  6: 00007FF7142DB178
> > v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+321544  7: 00007FF7142DAF7E
> > v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+321038  8: 00007FF71477CE2D
> > v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+547181  9:
> > 00007FF714701BBC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
> > 10: 00007FF714701BBC
> > v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748 11:
> > 00007FF71472C8CB v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+218123
> > 12: 00007FF714751182
> > v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+367810 13:
> > 00007FF71471EE22 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+162146
> > 14: 00007FF7146FEFDC
> > v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+31516 15:
> > 00007FF71421B050 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1536 16:
> > 00007FF71421B143 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1779 17:
> > 00007FF71421B522 v8::internal::Execution::TryCall+354 18:
> > 00007FF7141FD415 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::RunMicrotasks+501 19:
> > 00007FF7142DB8F0 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+323456 20:
> > 00007FF7142DAE37 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+320711 21:
> > 00007FF7142DB178 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+321544 22:
> > 00007FF7142DAF7E v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+321038 23:
> > 00007FF71477CE2D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+547181
> > 24: 00007FF714701BBC
> > v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748 25:
> > 00007FF7146FF0F1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+31793
> > 26: 00007FF7146FECDC
> > v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+30748 27:
> > 00007FF71421AFC3 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1395 28:
> > 00007FF71421A946 v8::internal::Execution::Call+182 29:
> > 00007FF71430633D v8::Function::Call+605 30: 00007FF713B6532D
> > node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+861 31: 00007FF713B6566C
> > node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+1692 32: 00007FF713B5D725
> > v8::internal::compiler::Operator::EffectOutputCount+229 33:
> > 00007FF713A12190
> > v8::internal::ParseInfo::max_function_literal_id+19776 34:
> > 00007FF713A129CE
> > v8::internal::ParseInfo::max_function_literal_id+21886 35:
> > 00007FF7139A0221 std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits
> > ::xsputn+49313 36: 00007FF7139A0658 std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits >::xsputn+50392 37:
> > 00007FF7139A2D2D std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits
> > ::xsputn+60333 38: 00007FF713A0D8AB v8::internal::ParseInfo::max_function_literal_id+1115 39:
> > 00007FF713B7EB2B uv_tty_set_vterm_state+7611 40: 00007FF713B941DC
> > uv_loop_init+908 41: 00007FF713B944FC uv_run+220 42: 00007FF713A9FD11
> > v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfBucketsOffset+803343:
> > 00007FF713B13EC5 node::Start+293 44: 00007FF713976A9C
> > RC4_options+340380 45: 00007FF714834E18
> > v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+1300824 46:
> > 00007FFDED1B7034 BaseThreadInitThunk+20 47: 00007FFDEEDA2651
> > RtlUserThreadStart+33

Any suggestion would be really helpful.